# Knockout Conditional Tool

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to add a conditional tool tip based on the menu item name.  I am new to knockout and not sure on the best way to approach this.

```
 <div id="pageMenu" data-bind="foreach: Pages">
        <div data-bind="visible: $data.accessAllowed() ">
            <a data-bind="click: $parent.openPage, css: { 'selected': Selected }"><div data-bind="text: MenuItemName"></div></a>
```

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do or make jsfiddle example?

Comment: <div data-bind="text: MenuItemName">  I want to add title but have it conditional based on the MenuItemName as it iterates.  data-bind="foreach: Pages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example title depends whether foo and bar have the same text. If you change foo's text to be foo for example the title will be title2

```
function bla(){
        self.text = ko.observable("Some text");
        self.bar = ko.observable("bar");
        self.foo = ko.observable("bar");
    }

ko.applyBindings(new bla());

<p data-bind="text: text, 
    attr:{
     'title': bar() === foo() ? 'title1' : 'title2'
     }">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should get me going in the right direction with the attributes.  I will have multiple pages returned and need a unique tool tip for each.

Comment: Once you go knockout you won't backout :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define function in your view model where you can put your condition for showing the tooltip or hide it like this :

```
function ViewModel(menuItemName) {
    ......
    self.visibleDiv = ko.computed(function () {
        //here you have the item that your are displaying.
        //So put here your logic and then 
        //you should return false or true
        .......
    });
}
```

then in your html

```
<div class="editor-label" data-bind="text: MenuItemName,visible: $root.visibleDiv(MenuItemName)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is should be what you are looking for.

```
<div id="pageMenu" data-bind="foreach: Pages">
  <div data-bind="visible: $data.accessAllowed() ">
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.openPage, css: { 'selected': Selected }">
      <div data-bind="attr : {'title' : ($data.MenuItemName() == 'criteria'? 'tooltip1' : 'tooltip2')} "></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.